# Update command updating wrong values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I am using C#, MS Access as database.I create class with properties of same as Table in database and trying to update database by this class properties using Reflection and class key value use in `where` condition for updatation purpose. Following is method which handle this:

```
    public void UpdateDBByObject(object objClass, string key, object keyValue, string tableName = null)
    {
        string _updateQuery = string.Empty;

        Type objType = objClass.GetType();
        List<PropertyInfo> propertyList = new List<PropertyInfo>(objType.GetProperties());

        Dictionary<string, object> _props = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        _updateQuery += "update " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName) ? objType.ToString().Split('.').LastOrDefault().TrimEnd('s') : tableName) + " set";

        foreach (var prop in propertyList)
        {
            string _name = prop.Name;
            if (_name == key) continue;

            _updateQuery += " [" + _name + "] = ?,";

            _props.Add(_name, prop.GetValue(objClass, null));
        }
        _updateQuery = _updateQuery.TrimEnd(',');
        _updateQuery += " where " + key + " = ?";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbConnection conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = _updateQuery;

        foreach (string value in _props.Keys)
        {
            object _addValue;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + value, _props.TryGetValue(value, out _addValue));
        }

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + key, keyValue);

        conn = GetOpenConnection();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        CloseConnection(conn);
    }
```

this method working but updating wrong values in database, i.e. for string value it update "-1" value, for DateTime it update min DateTime value. Please find out error and let me know.

Comment: props.TryGetValue(value, out _addValue) returns bool

Comment: @ankush kay karun rahilat bhau he...vadhiv programming...mala ghanta zepat nahiye kay lihilay code to

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S. mala pan que madhe ithka motha code takaychi ichha hot navti, pan que mag understand pan zal nasta n manun thakun dilla..!

Comment: @Priyank thanku for pointing my mistake..! Now I change the code. its working.

Comment: `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.` exeption throwing from ExecuteNonQuery statement

Comment: By removing milisecond part from DateTime parameter value, problem got solve now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TryGetValue(value,out object)` will out bool value hence for every time it will `bool` value.

```
 object outValue;
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + value, _props.TryGetValue(value, out outValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was adding bool value as paramenter in following line of code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + value, _props.TryGetValue(value, out _addValue));
```

After changing this code works fine.